# iOS - Animation of many different views

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to implement animations on many different `UIView` and `UIImageView` to make them consecutively fade in, move up and fade out one by one. This includes a very long series of animation, and I use simple `UIView` animation blocks with delay to make the moves happen one after another like this (which is a very small excerpt of the whole animation flow):

```
// Start animation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         redIcon1Image.alpha = 0.3;
                     }
                     completion:nil];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                          delay:0.1
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         redIcon1Image.frame = CGRectMake(33, 56, 73, 73);
                         redIcon1Image.alpha = 1;
                     }
                     completion:nil];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                          delay:0.2
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         redIcon2Image.alpha = 0.3;
                     }
                     completion:nil];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                          delay:0.3
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         redIcon2Image.frame = CGRectMake(127, 33, 68, 68);
                         redIcon2Image.alpha = 1;
                         doc1Image.alpha = 0.3;
                     }
                     completion:nil];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                          delay:0.4
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         doc1Image.alpha = 1;
                         redIcon2Image.frame = CGRectMake(123, 28, 73, 73);
                         redIcon3Image.alpha = 0.3;
                     }
                     completion:nil];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                          delay:0.5
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         redIcon3Image.frame = CGRectMake(221, 53, 68, 68);
                         redIcon3Image.alpha = 1;
                         doc2Image.alpha = 0.3;
                     }
                     completion:nil];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                          delay:0.6
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         redIcon3Image.frame = CGRectMake(218, 56, 73, 73);
                         doc2Image.alpha = 1;
                         doc3Image.alpha = 0.2;
                         glowView.alpha = 0.2;
                     }
                     completion:nil];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                          delay:0.7
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         doc3Image.alpha = 0.6;
                         glowView.alpha = 0.5;
                     }
                     completion:nil];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                          delay:0.8
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         doc3Image.alpha = 1;
                         glowView.alpha = 0.8;
                     }
                     completion:nil];
```

The thing is, although some views are set to be visible (alpha > 0) with delay, I can still see them being visible right when the animation starts. Could there be something wrong with the way I set the `delay`? I can't use the `completion` block in this situation because it would make a very complicated nested animation block. What should I do to make sure the animation runs smoothly? Please suggest and thanks.

**Edit:** I did set every view to be invisible, i.e. alpha = 0.0, before starting the animation. Also, I put all the animation in my `viewDidLoad` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an idea that might work,

Step 1: Declare an Array Property & Counter property

```
NSArray * blockArray;
int currentAnimationBlockIndex;
```

Step 2: Declare Animation Blocks

```
void (^block1)(void) = ^{
    redIcon1Image.alpha = 0.3;
};
void (^block2)(void) = ^{
    redIcon1Image.frame = CGRectMake(33, 56, 73, 73);
    redIcon1Image.alpha = 1;
};
void (^block3)(void) = ^{
    redIcon2Image.alpha = 0.3;
};
void (^block4)(void) = ^{
    redIcon2Image.frame = CGRectMake(127, 33, 68, 68);
    redIcon2Image.alpha = 1;
    doc1Image.alpha = 0.3;
};
void (^block5)(void) = ^{
    doc1Image.alpha = 1;
    redIcon2Image.frame = CGRectMake(123, 28, 73, 73);
    redIcon3Image.alpha = 0.3;
};
void (^block6)(void) = ^{
    redIcon3Image.frame = CGRectMake(221, 53, 68, 68);
    redIcon3Image.alpha = 1;
    doc2Image.alpha = 0.3;
};
void (^block7)(void) = ^{
    redIcon3Image.frame = CGRectMake(218, 56, 73, 73);
    doc2Image.alpha = 1;
    doc3Image.alpha = 0.2;
    glowView.alpha = 0.2;
};
void (^block8)(void) = ^{
    doc3Image.alpha = 0.6;
    glowView.alpha = 0.5;
};
void (^block9)(void) = ^{
    doc3Image.alpha = 1;
    glowView.alpha = 0.8;
    NSLog(@"9");
};
```

Step 3: Add Blocks To Array & Set Counter to 0

```
blockArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:block1, block2, block3, block4, block5, block6, block7, block8, block9, nil];

currentAnimationBlockIndex = 0;
```

Step 4: Add Animation Method

```
- (void) animateThroughBlocks {
    void (^animationBlock)(void) = blockArray[currentAnimationBlockIndex];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:animationBlock
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if (finished) {
                             currentAnimationBlockIndex = currentAnimationBlockIndex + 1;
                             if (currentAnimationBlockIndex == blockArray.count) {
                                 // completed animations!
                                 // reset counter
                                 currentAnimationBlockIndex = 0;
                             }
                             else {
                                 [self animateThroughBlocks];
                             }
                         }
                     }];

}
```

Step 5: Call Method

```
[self animateThroughBlocks];
```

Let me know how this goes for you!

Comment: This is the perfect solution. It saves me so much sweat and wasted time. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, I'll probably end up using this myself at some point!

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could chain animations easily: by declaring them as an array of animation blocks. Every completion block calls the next animation until the array is "finished".

Completely untested code, but that should give you the general idea:

```
UIView *view1, *view2, *view3;
NSArray *animations = @[
    ^{ view1.alpha = 1; view2.alpha = .3; },
    ^{ view2.alpha = 1; },
    ^{ view3.alpha = 0.5; }
];
void (^animate)(NSInteger index) = ^(NSInteger index){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.1 animations:^{
        void (^animationBlock)() = animations[index];
        animationBlock();
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (index < animations.count)
            animate(index+1);
    }];
};
animate(0);
```

I'm not really sure this is how you make recursive blocks (after all, that's what it is) from a memory-management point of view, but the idea is here.

Of course in this scenario, all animations have the same duration. You could build another NSArray (having the same length as `animations`) with the durations as NSNumbers, and use them as the `duration` parameter.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. I tried your code but then get bad access at the line `animate(index+1);`. How should I fix that?

Comment: Perhaps the test should be `if (index < animations.count - 1)`?

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to access the block from within the block.  A block is stored as soon as its declared, so when you define it here, 'animate()' as a variable doesn't exist yet.  Basically, when it tries to compile the 'animate()' variable, it can't find it because until it finishes defining it, 'animate()' doesn't exist.

Comment: That's why I said "I'm not really sure this is how you make recursive blocks" ;) Basically the idea is here, now it's up to you to make it functional.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the alpha of views to 0.0 *before* the animation starts? e.g.

```
redIcon1Image.alpha = 0.0;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     redIcon1Image.alpha = 0.3;
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

It isn't clear if you are doing so from your description, but that might explain why the views are initially visible.

Comment: Sorry for not describing clearer. I've edited my post, so yeah, I did set the views' alpha to 0.0.